# Why is this simple Python script failing? Python 2.6.6

Tags: python

Here's the script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class LEG(Structure): 
        _fields_ = [("distance_sm", c_float), ("distance_nm", c_float)]
```

Here's what I get when I run it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    class LEG(Structure): 
NameError: name 'Structure' is not defined
```

Yes, brand new to python, thanks for your help

Comment: You are extending a class that does not exist. Please provide full code.

Comment: Where is the `Structure` class?

Comment: Thanks guys, noob.  That was the full code, missing the import.

Comment: Be sure to mark as answer for the kind person below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the [`Structure`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) type from the `ctypes` module. You need to import that, as well as `c_float` and anything else you use from that module:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_float
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right on both points.